# Java sum algorithm not returning anything

Tags: java, algorithm, sum

I'm trying to solve the two sum algorithm on Leetcode:

Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target. You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice.

And came up with this:

```
public class Leet {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(twoSum(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, 2)));
    }

    public static int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
        int[] answer = null;
        int i = 0;
        for (int j = nums[i]; i < nums.length; i++) {
            for (int x : nums) {
                if (x != j & (j + x) == target) {
                    int x2 = java.util.Arrays.asList(nums).indexOf(x);
                    answer[0] = i;
                    answer[1] = x2;
                } else {
                    return nums;
                }

            }

        }
        System.out.println("leet method executed");

        return answer;
    }
}
```

The problem is it's not returning anything, not event the printed statement. Any ideas?

Comment: where/how do you call this method? show that also please

Comment: ` if (x != j & (j + x) == target) {` maybe the `&&` is your intend.

Comment: At least one thing is that your return variable is null, so your assignment to it in the inner if will fail

Comment: Sure that **nothing** is printed to the console? Because you only have **two** `return` statements, the first returns the unmodified input `num` which should have content, such it should get printed. The second one returns the `answer`, this could possibly be empty but in this case the *"leet method executed"* should at least get printed otherwise the statement would not be reached. Or does it throw an exception and the program crashes? Also your `answer` was never initialized to an actual `array`, it is `null` and you try to assign something with `answer[0] = i` that will probably crash.

Comment: I just executed the code and it prints `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` on my end. It used the `return nums;` statement in the `else` block in the very first iteration of this loop.

Comment: `for (int j = nums[i]; i < nums.length; i++)` looks suspicious. `j` gets set to`nums[0]` and then never changes again.   Is it possible that the loop was supposed to be `for (i=0; i < nums.length; ++i)`  with `int j = nums[i]` as the very first statement at the top of the loop?

Comment: Thanks I had no idea about the array. How could i declare an empty array and then fill it with the pair of numbers? I call the method from another class like this: public class Leettest extends Leet {
 
public static void main(String[] args){
 int[] example={1,2,3};
 twoSum(example,3);
 System.out.println("trial 1");
}
But all that happens is that it prints "trial 1"

Comment: If you know the maximal size of the array you initialize it with `int[] myArray = new int[5];` where `5` is the size. If you do not know the size than `array`s can not be used, they have a fixed length. However you can use *dynamic arrays* with `ArrayList` or use other `List` implementations. Your code (from the comments) prints nothing because you never save the result of `twoSum`, you print *"trial 1"*. If you do `int[] result = twoSum(...);` and then `println(Arrays.toString(result))` you will see that it returned the input `nums` in the `else`-block.

Comment: Also having thought about it, I don't understand why this results in j being set only once and never changing: for (int j = nums[i]; i < nums.length; i++). Doesn't j get reassigned with every iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See some fixes. Remember about array initialization and cases when values can be same in the array.

```
public class Solution {
    public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
        int[] answer = null;

        for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++) {
            int value = nums[i];

            for(int j=i+1;j<nums.length;j++) {
                int x=nums[j];
                if ((value+x)==target) {
                    answer = new int[2]; 
                    answer[0]=i;
                    answer[1]=j; 
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("leet method executed");

        if (answer == null) {
            return nums;
        }

        return answer;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see 2 things wrong or not intended in the program (leaving aside whether it's the best approach to the problem).

1. As stated in a comment, you should use `&&` instead of `&` for boolean AND.  `&` is bitwise AND, useful for integer bit twiddling.
2. You declare `answer` as an array, but never create space for it.  You need to say `int [] answer = new int[2];` or similar.

I haven't run the code, but if the test program ends with no output, check that you aren't getting a NullPointerException (caused by #2 above).

Comment: Could you elaborate on why & is better for integer comparison?

Comment: I didn't say better for integer comparison, but rather for bit twiddling with integer types.  Check out uses for bitwise AND/OR/NOT operators online.  Fascinating tricks used for decades either for simplifying logic or squeezing performance out of computers!

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget about null-checks and the case where no correct number-pair was found.

```
public static int[] twoSum(int[] numbers, int target) {
    if(Objects.isNull(numbers)){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("numbers is not allowed to be null");
    }

    for (int a=0;a<numbers.length;a++) {
        int first = numbers[a];

        for (int b=0;b<numbers.length;b++) {
            int second = numbers[b];

            if (first + second == target && a!=b) {
                return new int[] { first, second };
            }
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("there has to be a matching pair");
}
```

Comment: Your 2nd loop violates one of the conditions - i != j.  I think you could either add that as a condition (as the OP does) before return, or iterate with an i and j where j starts at j = i + 1